# Openstack on Fedora 20 install error

Tags: fedora, openstack

Okay I was trying to install OpenStack on Fedora 20 by going through this article http://openstack.redhat.com/Quickstart and encountered an error like below:

```
packstack --allinone

ERROR : Failed to run remote script, stdout: 
stderr: + trap t ERR
+ DEVICE=($(ip -o address show to 10.150.25.1 | cut -f 2 -d ' '))
++ ip -o address show to 10.150.25.1
++ cut -f 2 -d ' '
bash: line 3: ip: command not found
+ '[' '!' -z ']'
+ ip link show ''
bash: line 5: ip: command not found
++ t
++ exit 127
```

So it is evident from the error that it is not able to find the ip binary...but where to change that?

Shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `yum whatprovides '*bin/ip'` to find the package that contains the ip binary then install that package.